# C++ define function

Tags: c++

I would like to ask if there is a way to use define to create a function in C++ like that:

```
#define RequiredDamage(%1) ( (%1+1)*500 )
```

Could somebody help me to find better understanding of how `#define` actually works. What's the actual syntax to actually create a function like that, where could it be applied, is it a good idea to use it and why would I prefer it over a normal function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some specific aspect of `#define` you're confused about? Something that your book doesn't explain? Why don't you write an actual function?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Comment: `#define` is just like find and replace with regex. Your "Define Function" is commonly called a macro

Comment: Have you read about *macros* (not functions)? Have you seen examples of them? Can you please be more specific about what problems you have with them, elaborate on what you're wondering about?

Comment: In practice in your case you should avoid that and just *define* some `static int RequiredDamage(int x) { return (x*1)*500; }` function probably in some of your header file. And you need to read *more* about [C & C++ preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) notably [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor)

Comment: Yes, you can use the per-processor to create functions. But templates are more type safe, robust and powerful way to accomplish the same and more. Regardless, what you did is a macro, not a function.

Comment: @StoryTeller Templates aren't required, since `constexpr` exists.

Comment: @underscore_d - I think you didn't get what I meant by crating functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide an argument in your macro definition:

```
#define RequiredDamage(x)  ( (x+1)*500 )
```

Comment: you should mention fallacies with macros and why not to use them in C++.

Comment: @TheTechel What alternative is there in C++? Inline functions?

Comment: `constexpr` functions are even better, since they may actually be evaluated right away.