# #define OUTPUT(j) count++ what does this do?

Tags: c

i want to translate this to c#. but i am stuck at the output.

what does "#define OUTPUT(j)" do?

ive seen this. 
[C++ Define function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243215/c-define-function)

it looklike func defining but input param j  is unrelated to count.

code is from : 
https://github.com/smart-tool/smart/blob/master/source/algos/raita.c

```
#define OUTPUT(j) count++  


void preBmBc(unsigned char *x, int m, int bmBc[]) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < SIGMA; ++i)
      bmBc[i] = m;
   for (i = 0; i < m - 1; ++i)
      bmBc[x[i]] = m - i - 1;
}

int search(unsigned char *x, int m, unsigned char *y, int n) {
   int j, bmBc[SIGMA], count;
   unsigned char c, firstCh, *secondCh, middleCh, lastCh;
    if(m<2) return -1;

   /* Preprocessing */
   BEGIN_PREPROCESSING
   preBmBc(x, m, bmBc);
   firstCh = x[0];
   secondCh = x + 1;
   middleCh = x[m/2];
   lastCh = x[m - 1];
   END_PREPROCESSING

   /* Searching */
   BEGIN_SEARCHING
   count = 0;
   j = 0;
   while (j <= n - m) {
      c = y[j + m - 1];
      if (lastCh == c && middleCh == y[j + m/2] &&
          firstCh == y[j] &&
          memcmp(secondCh, y + j + 1, m - 2) == 0)
         OUTPUT(j);
      j += bmBc[c];
   }
   END_SEARCHING
   return count;
}
```

Comment: it get's someone fired the moment it hits peer review

Comment: This is a HORRIBLE code.

Comment: `OUTPUT(j)` will be replaced by `count++` by preprocessor. No idea, why it's needed, but anyways.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

Comment: Gotta love open source, this github project is pure gold. Every file includes main.h where main() is placed, for the sake of greatness. I particularly like define.h with `#define UNDEFINED -1`, `#define HALFDEFINED -2`.

Comment: the min/max with a macro, a great classic ^^

Comment: Apparently the code compares the execution times of several string matching algorithms. It also has macros to start and stop timers. Where an actual algorithm would report or store a match, this variant just increments a counter as a quick check whether all matches were found. I don't think this code is meant as production code.

Comment: @Lundin for consistency reason a `#define DEFINED -4` is very missing ^^

Comment: @bh_earth0 you do what you want but it seems a good idea to delete your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor directive

```
#define OUTPUT(j) count++
```

makes the preprocessor to replace every occurrence of `OUTPUT(j)` with `count++` where `j` is variable and can be used in the patter part of the directive.

The code

```
#define OUTPUT(j) count++

int count(4);
OUTPUT(1234);
std::cout << count << '\n';
```

is translated to

```
int count(4);
count++;
std::cout << count << '\n';
```

by the preprocessor and then compiled by the compiler.

The output of this code is `5`. The argument is ignored since `j` is not used.